# How can I show the actual port mappings for configured but not connected ssh forwarding ports?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to find a way to verify **after configuration** that an SSH local port forwarding rule is present and correct.  I use the following to create the forwarding entry:

```
> OPTS="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes
> nohup ssh $OPTS -N -g -L 65001:192.168.15.159:8080 localhost &
```

Once this returns, the forwarding rule should be running and available for use.  I've found suggestions to use both `netstat` and `lsof` to show the current status of ports, but neither of these will show me anything other than "the local port is open and listening".  What I want to get is both that AND confirmation of what the destination address:port is.

```
lwobker@lwobker-vms:~$ sudo netstat -tplnd | grep 65001
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:65001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29076/ssh           
tcp6       0      0 :::65001                :::*                    LISTEN      29076/ssh    

### or...

lwobker@lwobker-vms:~$ lsof -i tcp | grep 65001
ssh       29076 lwobker    4u  IPv4 13036241      0t0  TCP *:65001 (LISTEN)
ssh       29076 lwobker    5u  IPv6 13036242      0t0  TCP *:65001 (LISTEN)


### shows port up and listening and PID, but not the destination/mapped port
```

The mapped host:port state is required for the port forwarding to do its job, so that information has to be SOMEWHERE...  ;-)

Comment: The forwarding is not performed until someone tries to connect to the listening port, so there's no way to know if the forwarding is "correct" until then. After the forwarding is performed, the only way to list it is with the `~#` escape. The "SOMEWHERE" is somewhere internal to the ssh client, so if you used the `-N` option, the only way is with debugger.

Comment: OK I should have said "how do I know if it's **configured** correctly?"  I need a command that shows me all of the sessions that are currently listening, but with the destination host/port info.  Netstat/lsof tell me that the port is listening, but not where it's mapped to.

Comment: The port is not magically "mapped" to a forwarding. The way it works is: you have a ssh process which listen on a port, and when someone connects to that port, it accepts the connection and forwards it over an ssh channel. Only after that there would be an active forwarding which you could list with `~#`. Before that, nothing whatsoever is "configured", except that ssh is listening on a port, and will complain if it's not able to listen to that port.

Comment: Everything about how ssh forwards connection is __internal to ssh__, and as I said, there's no way to poke at that info in an already running ssh process other than with a debugger. If you start `ssh` with `-vvv` it will show you copious debugging info, probably containing info about the "potential" forwardings, too.